# .valueChanges stops emitting after passing a new FormGroup object

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

An issues I notice on Angular 17.2. `valueChanges` stops emitting a new values after passing a new object to `formGroup` directive after form submit.
I have inited a tiny project to demo that
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vrf16c?file=src%2Fmain.ts.
It is in `control-error.directive.ts` as well as `App.component`. As far as I remember for example in Angular 10 it works as expected.

Comment: You're creating a new FormGroup and reassigning a value of `this.formGroup` with it but you're not resubscribing to this new FormGroup.